# AWS CORS config, error 403 forbidden on file upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I went through several troubleshooting guides, but can't seem to find a solution yet. I am uploading image files to my S3 bucket through a test website on http://localhost:3000.

If I set `Write Objects` to **Allow** on *Public Access* on the bucket the files are uploaded OK. However if I remove the checkboxes from the public access, and leave my CORS like this:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

the file won't upload and I will get an error:

```
POST https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads 403 (Forbidden)
```

Any help appreciated.

Update:

headers:

[image: aws response]

[image: request]

Comment: It's probably best if you would sniff your HTTP traffic and submit the relevant headers here. Both the request headers and the response headers; both for the preflight request (if any) and the actual upload.

Comment: added response headers

Comment: Response headers look fine. This suggests the problem is not in the server but in the client. Allow me to recommend this article; it helped me a lot in the past. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: thanks. Don't really understand why it's working when setting full public permissions though.

Comment: This may be due to the fact that your client isn't transmitting cookies; if the server demands an authentication cookie, then that might explain the 403. From aforementioned article: "Standard CORS requests do not send or set any cookies by default. In order to include cookies as part of the request, you need to set the XMLHttpRequest's `.withCredentials` property to true."

Comment: I suspected there might be something with the IAM settings, but after I gave my AWS user admin rights on all s3 operations it did not start working either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149943/discussion-between-ruud-helderman-and-the-whiz-of-oz).